# ECS app service doesn't seem to be able to connect to mongo service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I've got two services an app service and a mongodb service both on different task definitions. I want the app to be able to connect mongodb however it doesn't seem to be able to fine it.

When creating the mongodb service I've defined a service discovery name and I thought I could use this domain endpoint in the connection string in the app in order to connect to it.

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "service discovery name"? If you have "two different task definitions", then you need to assume, that each one can be deployed on a different node/cluster (i.e. connecting to `mongodb` for example won't work; i.e. "linking" can be done within the same task definition only). Apart from that, I'd check security group settings as the most likely candidate for connectivity issues.

Comment: Sure @SzymonBiliński what I mean it when I completed the setup for the service which runs the mongodb task definition I gave a service name of mongodb.local which has been created in route53 now I was thinking because its in the same vpc I could talk to the service by just having the hostname in the connection string as the declared service name, mongodb://mongodb.local:27017/database.

Comment: Decided to go with the easier solution of having a database managed on RDS.